# Convert nested dictionary into a multiple-column indexes dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
| Week | info |
| ---- | ---- |
| 1    |{'Info': 'text', 'value': 94615}, {'Info': 'text_2', 'value': 111968}|
| 2    |{'Info': 'text', 'value': 234}, {'Info': 'text_2', 'InfoB': 236}|
| 3    |{'Info': 'text', 'value': 524523}, {'Info': 'text_2', 'InfoB': 5555}|
```

I would like to open up the dictionaries under info and am thinking that I should maybe re-shape the dataframe into a multiple-column index... perhaps by converting it into a multiple-column indexes dataframe as follows:

```
| Week | info             |
|      | text   | text_2  |
| ---- | ------ | ------- |
| 1    | 94615  | 111968  |  
| 2    | 234    | 236     |  
| 3    | 524523 | 5555    |
```

Any suggestions how can I do this?
Also what's the best way to perform aggregation to this data, (e.g. mean of text, sum of week 1) pivot table perhaps?

Comment: Why do you say the dictionaries are 'nested'?

Comment: The fact that some of the keys change from 'value' to 'InfoB' in the second dictionary makes this difficult. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first is necessary change format of dictionaries and then convert to DataFrame like:

```
L =  [dict([tuple(y.values()) for y in x]) for x in df.pop('info')]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
   Week    text  text_2
0     1   94615  111968
1     2     234     236
2     3  524523    5555
```

Another idea:

```
f = lambda x: dict([tuple(y.values()) for y in x])
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('info').apply(f)))
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume the order of the dictionaries will be consistent when using `values()`?

Comment: @Bill - yes, it is necessary here.

Comment: Would be safer to use the keys I think, but based on the example data, it seems that the keys themselves are not consistent so I guess this is the best you can do.